KiCad Pin Assignments


I am creating my own Numpad while loosely following Robert Ferenacs guide on Youtube. He did everything in EasyEDA whereas I wanted to use KiCad. I honestly do not know what I am doing. After finishing I ran ERC and got 30 errors and 999+ warnings that all have to do with pin assignment and power. In the picture I assigned output to pin one on the diodes and get the error "Pins of type output and output are connected". Is this a concern?
Also I have no clue why he chose Zener Diodes but i just went with it since they will never reach 20V.
I imported all my parts using JLC2KiCadLib function in the terminal. Almost all pin types were unspecified and I assigned passive to all capacitors and resistors. I also think I am doing something wrong with power and ground. I originally had the GNDREF symbol but switched them for GNDPWR because of How to connect these +3.3V power pins/labels?
In the second picture all the warnings are "Pins of type power input and unspecified are connected" or "Pins of type unspecified and unspecified are connected"
Also, I haven't specified whether power flags are input and output.
Do I need to clear these errors and warnings before creating the PCB or will it matter?

Why it's a concern: If you have two outputs connected, this can create a conflict in the circuit as outputs generally cannot be tied directly together.
What to do: Double-check how you're wiring the diodes and ensure that the diode cathodes (the pins you’re likely connecting) are going to a proper net like a column or row (not another output pin).
You can use the Power Flags feature in KiCad to define power nets (like +3.3V, GND) and mark them with the appropriate input/output flags.
I believe you may need to create bus flags for each switched rail as "bidirectional" for row and columns. But never tried it.
